# GSON getting arrays

Tags: java, gson

I'm fairly new to GSON and I was wondering how to store an array from a json page, for example if I have:

```
{capitals:[{"alabama":"montgomery"},{"alaska":"juneau"},{"arizona":"phoenix"}]}
```

I'm unsure of how to do this, previously I've had pages a name and information inside of them (like so),

```
"name":{"var1":"aaa", "var2":"bbb"}
```

and I've been able to create a class for that, just a bit confused of how to process arrays.

Comment: It's not a valid JSON string. Test [HERE](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: I just did test it on that website, it says that it's a valid JSON